# header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); Not allowing CORS request

Tags: php, cors

I have a PHP file which generates a JSON document.

I've set the `header` as follows but am still getting an error.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Error message:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I've tried explictly allowing mysubdomain.mydomain.com using

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com');
```

But I still get the error.

Comment: Are you getting the header in your Chrome's web inspector's network tab when you make the request? Or using the curl command line?

Comment: Thanks, by using curl from the command line I was able to diagnose the issue. It was actually an error in the PHP code later on that was causing the problems.

Comment: You're welcome. Always remember to check and debug output first :). I have posted my comment as an answer so that you can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look there is anything wrong with the code that sets the header, but you may want to check if the header is actually being set. Use `curl -i http://yourapp` to check the response headers being sent to debug it. Alternatively, you can use the network tab in Google Chrome's web inspector, or the Network tool in Firefox's Web Developer tools.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did not get anything useful in the Network tool. However, it shows `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` while making curl call

Answer (score 5):

with htaccess file you can try to set :

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH,DELETE"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type,Authorization,Cache-Control,X-Requested-With, X-XSRF-TOKEN"
```

Or with PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, x-xsrf-token, x_csrftoken, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With');
```

Answer (score 1):

Such a situation may arise when an error occurs on the requested page. In this case the error page sets headers, that likely has no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.