# Can't fetch data from my API server in React

Tags: php, reactjs, rest, api

I try to fetch data (list of files in folder) from my server `https://www.my-site.com/api` where I've got `index.php` file which is

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $dir = "./photos"; //path

    $list = array(); //main array

    if(is_dir($dir)){
        if($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){

                if($file == "." or $file == ".."){
                    //...
                } else {
                    $list3 = array(
                        'url' => $file);
                        array_push($list, $list3);
                }
            }
        }

        $return_array = array('photos'=> $list);

        echo json_encode($return_array);
    }
?>
```

and in my React app i try to use `fetch`

```
fetch('https://www.my-site.com/api', {
   method: 'GET',
   redirect: 'follow',
   headers: {
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

but the result is `CORS request did not succeed` and `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`. When im using Postman, everything it's ok, and I get json object with data I wanted.

Comment: You should inspect your response headers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189756/headeraccess-control-allow-origin-not-allowing-cors-request for example.

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

To `.htaccess` file

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128176/reactjs-api-data-fetching-cors-error

Comment: I have add `proxy` to `package.json` but now i get this error: `error SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"`

Comment: Try log the plain text response

Comment: I use response.text() instead .json() i i get my-site.com/api HTML and it's 404, but in browser in my-site.com/api i get json

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I tryed to fetch data from `my-site.com/api` but I should fetch from `my-site.com/api/index.php`